# Insert blob on WebSQL

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, web-sql

I'm trying to save a blob image into sqlite (Web SQL) on an Apache Cordova App which is run on Android.

I've figured out how to create the blob and obtain it from a local file. The problem is that on the database, instead of being saved the blob, saves an String which states [Object Blob]

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://localhost/image.jpg",true);
xmlhttp.responseType = 'blob';
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(xmlhttp.readyState==4){
    var product_image = xmlhttp.response;
    db.transaction(tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO scans(product_image) VALUES (?)",[product_image]), errorCB);
  }
}
xmlhttp.send();
```

In fact, product_image returns a jpeg blob object. But as stated before, when I do SELECT the result returns [Object Blob]

This is how I create the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scans(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, product_image BLOB)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebSQL does not support binary data directly.

Typically, binary data is converted into some text format like Base64, and stored as text in the database.

Alternatively, use [blob literals](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#litvalue) and the [hex() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#hex) to treat blob values as hex strings at the interface between SQL and JavaScript.